# Faucet Removal Problem

Tags: faucet

I need to replace my kitchen faucet but have never seen one like this before. My sink is a 4 hole, but this seems to be all one assembly. I does have a sprayer on it also, which is the hose with the nut.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture of the top portion of the faucet would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the hose attachment at point A as shown below.

Then remove the hex nuts from the threaded pipe at the point B.

These two steps will free up the U shaped washer and plastic spacer under it and allow the central faucet assembly to become loose.

[image]

You may also have to remove the fastener at the location shown at the lower portion of your photo. There may actually be two of these to remove, one in each of the faucet holes for faucet types that mount into separate holes. These two additional fasteners typically hold a decorative plate above in place the covers these holes in cases where a single handle style faucet is used.

[image]

Comment: Just want to thank you so much for this. I took a picture, put it through Google Lens, it brought me here, and your answer helped me get it out of there fairly easily. You make a great difference by taking the time to do a great answer like this. Thanks!